# invalid argument C:\Users\Dar laptops\face_recognition\face_mask_detector_4\Keras-FaceMask-Detection-System\data\with_mask\1.jpg

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I have a text file which has some paths in it. The problem is that my windows User name is space separated and when i run my python file to read it. It only read till space and ignores everything else.

> C:\Users\Dar
> laptops\face_recognition\face_mask_detector_4\Keras-FaceMask-Detection-System\data\with_mask\1.jpg

how can i read the space and all the path.

Comment: Hello sir, good day. Did you try to change the space to a url encode? `C:\Users\Dar%20laptops\face_recognition\face_mask_detector_4\Keras-FaceMask-Detection-System\data\with_mask\1.jpg`

Comment: it is not a url. It is a text file which should run in command line.

Comment: Put the whole path between double quotes.

Comment: already tried it